# JSON Object passed to External JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, design-patterns, external

I was looking at [FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) and saw that they use a pretty cool technique to pass options into an external script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js">
{
    overrideConsole: false,
    startInNewWindow: true,
    startOpened: true,
    enableTrace: true
}
</script>
```

What is the name of this technique and how does it work?

Comment: Is this similar to JSONP? http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an automatic variable-passing-technique as you may think.

All their code does is loop through all the `script` tags until they find the one which loaded their code (by comparing the `src` attribute to a regular expression (`/(firebug-lite(?:-\w+)?(?:\.js|\.jgz))(?:#(.+))?$/;`).

If it finds the tag, it simply gets the `.innerHTML` of the `script` tag, and evaluates it.

I guess this (unnamed) techique isn't relevant in the real-world, as we don't have a guaranteed method of finding which `script` tag refers to our library (especially as it is common for all script's to be combined into one script file on live servers).

<s>Furthermore, I have my doubts over how cross-browser this is; as it certainly doesn't go by the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1), which states:</s>

Having said that (and thought about it): the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) states that the browser shouldn't interpret both. However this isn't relevant with this technique. The browser doesn't have to interpet both, as the content of the script is read in through `innerHTML` (and even if it did read in the content, it doesn't do any harm anyway). Aslong as the browser conforms to the spec, and loads the URI (which all browsers do), there's no problem! (apart from not knowing/ guaranteeing which `script` tag your library belongs to).

> The script may be defined within the
>   contents of the SCRIPT element or in
>   an external file. If the src attribute
>   is not set, user agents must interpret
>   the contents of the element as the
>   script. If the src has a URI value,
>   user agents must ignore the element's
>   contents and retrieve the script via
>   the URI.

(i.e., don't interpret both).

Comment: Open the https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js file; and search for 'var getScriptURL' and 'var options=fileOptions.split(",");'

Comment: @Theo: `fileOptions` are for the "Script URL Options" (http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#ScriptURLOptions). What do you want me to look at `getScriptUrl` for?

Comment: @Matt I didn't mean you, I was adding to your answer.  I meant 'var url=getScriptURL(script);', is where what you explained happens.

Comment: @Theo: Ahhhhhhhh :). I'm no longer so confused!

Comment: @Matt: Nicely done sir. I had wondered about this got scared off when I saw that it seemed to go counter to the spec.  So what I am getting from what you are saying is that is irrelevant that the contents of the script tag be javascript; it could be XML, HTML, or arbitrary text as long as one's code is set up to interpret it, yes?

Comment: @Matthew: I didn't think as far ahead as sticking HTML/ XML in there, but yeah I guess you could. I've tried it in the latest versions of IE, Firefox and Chrome, and non evaluate the script content if a `src` is set (even if the `src` points to an invalid URI). I'd still be a little bit wary of putting non-valid JS in there. Not only does it "not seem right", but **if** a browser decides to evaluate it, you'll get a JS parse error (consider wrapping the HTML/ XML in quotes/ JS comments `/* */` to make it valid JS (escaping quotes etc. aside).

Answer (score 2):

Further to @Matt's answer, and to clarify my comment:

```
var doc = Firebug.browser.document;
var script = doc.getElementsByTagName("script")[index];
var url = getScriptURL(script);
var isExternal = url && url != doc.location.href;

try
{
  if(isExternal)
  {
    Ajax.request({url:url, onSuccess:renderProcess, onFailure:onFailure})
  }
  else
  {
    var src = script.innerHTML;
    renderProcess(src)
  }
}
catch(e)
{
  onFailure()
}
```