# Passing Options to a Linked JavaScript File

Tags: javascript

I noticed this method for setting options for Firebug Lite:
http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#ScriptJSONOptions

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js">
{
  overrideConsole: false,
  startInNewWindow: true,
  startOpened: true,
  enableTrace: true
}
</script>
```

Is there a reference anywhere for how this is supposed to work? Which browsers support it and how doe one access the options from the linked script?

I usually work around it by creating another  tag above it with options, but this looks cleaner.

Comment: There were some [good answers on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135309/json-object-passed-to-external-javascript-cool-technique) a brief while back. Basically, Firebug scans the document for whichever script tag loaded it, and parses the `innerHTML`. It should be cross-browser for the main ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug would need to [parse that information](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfWdD/) itself.

Comment: Thanks! I thought something more magical was happening. The link to another question in Bryan's comment above is helpful as well.